# Load file into tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a file picker and want to load HTML and XML files that are chosen into the tinyMCE editor textarea.

I have the below code and it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
height: 400,
browser_spellcheck: true,
plugins: "code,table,textcolor,save,preview,searchreplace,advlist,textcolor,hr,fullscreen",
toolbar: [
'save | undo redo | styleselect | fontsizeselect | bold strikethrough italic forecolor backcolor | link image | alignleft aligncenter alignright | numlist bullist | indent  outdent | table | code | fullscreen'
],
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
  win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = 'editor';
  console.log(win.document.getElementById(field_name).value);
},
save_onsavecallback: function () {
var doc = tinymce.get('content').getDoc();
console.log('Content: ', doc);
}
});
</script>
```

textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="editor"></textarea>
```

To be precise, here is what occurs. I am presented with a file picker but when I click to open the document the chosen file is not input into the textarea.

Images below.

[Image of file choser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk5qB.png)

[If i were to open one of these files they would not be in tinymce textarea...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vavsL.png)

Comment: So what in particular is not working?  You have provided no actual details.  Please review How to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Michael, in order to make it more clear what the issue is I added more detail towards the end of my post. Thank you for reviewing my problem and I look forward to your feedback and assistance.

Comment: Well your code appears to do nothing with the selected file so I would not expect it to "appear" in the editor.  Have you seen this: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/file-picker/

Also - exactly what types of files are you allowing to be uploaded?  What would you want TinyMCE to do it you picked an XML file??

Comment: Michael, yes, I have seen the file-picker demo. That is for image files, and I want to do .HTML and .XML files. As for your last sentence, I believe you are asking what I want to do with an XML file? If so, just to parse/make the file's contents appear in the textarea "as is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last response to my comments on the case you don't want the TinyMCE file picker capability - you need to build a UI that allows for selecting a file, uploading it, and then sending the HTML representation of the file back to the browser so you can insert that HTML into the editor via the `setContent()` API.

I would use a custom toolbar button to open a "dialog" that is really a separate HTML page with a file selection UI.  Once the file is selected you can POST that to your server.  The server can open / process the file as needed and send back HTML results to your "dialog".  The "dialog" can then use the TinyMCE `setContent()` API to load the data into the editor.

A simple file picker won't do everything you need.

Comment: Thanks.  So probably jQuery or ajax for upload UI right?

Comment: There are many ways to get it done but using AJAX would be a pretty basic requirement.