# Uploading a file in TinyMCE

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

In ASP.NET MVC I am using TinyMCE 4.7.8 (2018-02-26). I want to upload a Pdf/Doc/Excel file and add an anchor for it at editor HTML. I am able to upload the image and get back the uploaded url to add image at editor this works fine.

I am looking answer for two things a) Is link plugin is the correct way to upload the pdf and doc into system since I have not found any specific plugin for file handling in community edition! b) In my method filePicker I am creating dynamic html to handle the posted file, again it this approach is just a work around or there any way in TinyMCE to handle **file** type?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".TinyMCEEditor",
    branding: false,
    height: 500,
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    file_browser_callback_types: 'file image',
    automatic_uploads: true,
    images_upload_url: '/Content/UploadContentImg',
    file_picker_types: 'file image',
    file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
        debugger;
        // Provide image and alt text for the image dialog
        if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
            imageFilePicker(callback, value, meta);
        }

        // Provide file and text for the link dialog
        if (meta.filetype == 'file') {
            filePicker(callback, value, meta);
            //callback('mypage.html', { text: 'My text' });
        }

        // Provide alternative source and posted for the media dialog
        if (meta.filetype == 'media') {
            //callback('movie.mp4', { source2: 'alt.ogg', poster: 'image.jpg' });
        }
    },
    templates: [{
            title: 'Test template 1',
            content: 'Test 1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Test template 2',
            content: 'Test 2'
        }
    ]
});


function imageFilePicker(callback, value, meta) {

};

function filePicker(callback, value, meta) {

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');

    //input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    input.click();

    debugger;
};
```

Comment: Image is posted to '/Content/UploadContentImg'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load file into tinyMCE editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458042/load-file-into-tinymce-editor)

Comment: @StefanCrain, I checked the above question and surly user want quite similar solution but I wonder if there is any possible way to handle a file like an image into configuration. At the end of it in both cases(image/doc-pdf) I need to have an upload and submit button!

Comment: The difference is HTML has a tag to handle images (`img`) but not a "file" so what you want to do with that file and what HTML you want to create to reference that file is inherently different and specific to your application.

Comment: @MichaelFromin, Sir, you sound me very logical but still I believe since we are in conversation to the context of a dedicated plugin that deals with file, image and media in TinyMCE content editor thus we must have special written codes for that tag formation job!